# index(of: not appearing for [[String:Any]]

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary

For finding index of element in `array` we use [index(of:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index)

```
let array = ["Amit","Peter", "Jhon"]
let i = array.index(of: "Peter")
print(i)//gives 1
```

Now i am using `[[String:Any]]` which is `array(of dictionary)`

```
let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]
```

Unfortunately `index(of:` not getting populate. Why ?

Comment: IF you meant to have a string:string value don't do it string:any until the need to

Comment: @Sh_Khan actually my array may be `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 1):

Because of `Any` as what happens behind the scene of `indexOf` is value comparing and for sure value oftype any can't be compared

```
 let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]
```

change to

```
 let arrayKeyPair: [[String:String]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]
```

Comment: because they have dictionary array not single array.i was checked and giving error like Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String : String]'

Comment: then you're passing string to indexOf instead of value like **["name":"value"]**

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]
    let index = arrayKeyPair.index(where: {$0["name"] as? String == "Peter"})
```

Answer (score 0):

[index(of:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index) works on array where the elements conforms to the equatable protocol. you are using `Any` therefore it will not work.

If you really want to use **index(of:)**, use `[[String:String]]`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]

    let indexOfA = indexOfQuestion(id: "Peter") // 0
            print(indexOfA)

    func indexOfValue(id: String) -> Int {
            return arrayKeyPair.index { (question) -> Bool in
                return question["name"] as? String == id
                } ?? NSNotFound
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]

let arrayKeyPair: [[String:Any]] = [["name":"Amit"],["name":"Peter"],["name":"Jhon"]]
let index = arrayKeyPair.index(where: {$0["name"] as? String == "Amit"})
```